# How can you assure a torque wrench is working properly?

Tags: tools, torque

Torquing to a manufacturer's spec is important when working on an engine but I've wondered how do you properly determine if an adjustable torque wrench has been zeroed out over it's life and is still accurate?  Is there a life to a torque wrench?

Comment: You'd have to use a calibrated testing unit on the torque wrench though some (electronic?) torque wrenches may have some kind of zero'ing feature.

Comment: It might be a ghetto system but if you really want to know without getting to particular measuring gizmo you could compare it to other torque wrenches.
otherwise an example could be in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUD81N_TlS8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is calibration equipment to zero torque wrenches**

Snap-On makes this one.

[image]

[Here is a procedure](http://buy1.snapon.com/PRODUCTS/TORQUE/pdf/techangle/Internet%20Accessible%20CALIBRATION%20PROCEDURE.pdf) for calibrating one of their digital torque wrenches.

To answer your question

> I've wondered how do you properly determine if an adjustable torque wrench has been zeroed out over it's life and is still accurate?

There are various procedures to accomplish this based upon manufacturer.  Many Craftsman outlets will perform the task free of charge as will Snap-On and Matco in their trucks.  If not, there are typically procedures available if you have the measuring equipment.

> Is there a life to a torque wrench?

Some are infinitely rebuildable by replacing failed or out of spec components over time.  I have not seen one that isn't but typically I procuring 'higher end' equipment as was a mechanic in another life.

Comment: Torque wrenches absolutely do fall out of spec, and sometimes the internals reach a point where adjustments no longer bring them back in due to worn springs, etc. The quality of the product does have an effect on longevity, but all springs wear out eventually.